# Python upload handler

Tags: python, html, json

I have got this error as trying to upload a file to my web page:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./upload_handler.py", line 12, in 
    if term.file: 
NameError: name 'term' is not defined

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: </form>
    <form action="upload_handler.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
   </form>

Comment: import cgi, json
import os


def main():
 print("Content-Type: application/json\n\n")
 form = cgi.FieldStorage()
 term = form.getvalue('fileToUpload')

if term.file: 
 with file("uploaded.file", 'w') as outfile:
  outfile.write(term.file.read())




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Comment: If `term` is a keyword argument to based on form data, it could be undefined. Make sure that `kwargs["term"]` is defined, it that's how your framework works. We also need background on your program, how your form works, and the framework you use.

Comment: Thank you Robert.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome! Didn't think I would get the answer in the comments. :-)